# Does picking up a weapon give any stored/leftover criticals?

Tags: team-fortress-2

With the [Gunmettle](http://www.teamfortress.com/gunmettle/) update it is now possible to pick up weapons from fallen foes (provided you are playing the same class as them).

There are also some weapons that stockpile crits through certain actions. The [Frontier Justice](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Frontier_Justice) for example, will give guaranteed critical hits based on the amount of Sentry Kills when the Sentry is taken down.

Assuming I'm playing the same class and pick up a weapon that still had crits left at the time of it's owner's demise, will those crits still 'exist' on the weapon?

Comment: Not what you're asking but related: someone found that [ÜberCharge is carried over by dropped mediguns](https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/3bx8tg/uber_drops_carry_through_dropped_mediguns/) — _if it's from a teammate who suicides_. So fairly useless, but evidence that the kind of thing is possible.

Comment: On a side note, what @KevinReid said has now been switched... Ubercharge is now carried over by dropped mediguns **except** if the person who dropped it suicides.  If they suicided, it carries over from where it was during their previous death (anti-griefing measure?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - stored crits (such as those obtained from the Diamondback, Manmelter, and Frontier Justice) are lost upon death and cannot be traded with other players through suicide or weapon exchange.

(source: I tested a few minutes ago)